# What is required for an IIS site to send error details to the browser?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am receiving a Server Error on an ASP Classic site running on IIS 7.5.

I have "Send Errors To Browser" set to `True`, however I still receive the following error screen:
[image: 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource your are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IIS is hijacking your classic ASP app's response. In your `web.config` file ensure that the following is configured:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also make sure that you've enabled "Send Errors To Browser" in the ASP configuration feature for your site in IIS manager:

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is no `web.config` in a Classic ASP site.  Should I create one and add that setting?

Comment: @smartcaveman - yes. `web.config` in IIS7.x isn't just specific to ASP.NET. It can be used to config IIS settings as well, such as IIS's custom error handling.

Comment: @smartcaveman - I updated the answer to show exactly what it should look like.

Comment: those are my settings, as I posted in the question.  I will create a web.config and get back to you.

Comment: @MatthewLock in what way doesn't it work? Why not ask a new question, refer to this one and explain in detail what doesn't work. Also include the relevant configuration info which we know nothing about.

Comment: Fair enough. Will do next time.

Comment: Perfect solution. I already knew 'Send Erros To Browser', hence it was correctly set. As I was accessing external server, the creation of the 'web.config' AT THE APPLICATION ROOT completed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my site needed to be an IIS Application, rather than just a virtual directory,